# HTTPS server not working on Android mobile phone but HTTP does?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, express

I am currently learning how to create servers with Node js and other Javascript apis, and I've built a both HTTP and HTTPS server which works fine on every pc navigator of my nat network but when I try the https server on my android mobile device with: https://192.168.1.20:8443 which is where I built my node.js server it won't load and say the page is not working although it works with http.

I would also like to know if I could make my server visible or access to it with my router public ip address and how could I do that.

This is my server code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var cors = require('cors');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('host.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('host.cert', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use('/work', express.static('/.'))
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    console.log('Servidor en marxa.');
});


var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(8080);
httpsServer.listen(8443);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some hours later I have just realized I needed to forward my router ports to where I have my Node.js server built. I had to port forward both the HTTP (#80) and HTTPS (#443) to grant the access by public ip address.

Also had to modify part of my Javascript Server code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var cors = require('cors');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('host.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('host.cert', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    console.log('Servidor en marxa.');
});

// your express configuration here

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80,"0.0.0.0");
httpsServer.listen(443,"0.0.0.0");
var io = require("socket.io")(httpServer);
```